# Add second Docker Image into Main image in YML

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, yaml

I am not a docker expert at all, but I am trying to solve a problem I have been dealing with for a long time. For the record,  I want to spin up a container using tomcat, and then add another image's contents into that container.

When using

```
FROM tomcat:10.0-jdk8-openjdk-slim
```

It has become cumbersome to go back and build a new release image for every application every time there is a new vulnerability with tomcat. Having to manually go generate new releases, update all of the YMLs and pull them down on multiple systems and redeploy is a huge time sink.

So I tried doing it this way, where there are multiple services, and one depends on the other. This would allow me to just do an update when there is a new tomcat version, but not change the application running in that tomcat. However this doesn't seem to work the way I was hoping, or maybe I am not understanding something.

```
services:
  soa:
    image: repo/appname:X.X.X
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:10.0-jdk8-openjdk-slim
    depends_on:
      - soa
    ... rest of yml ...
```

The soa image is just an image that contains

- some libraries to be put in /usr/local/tomcat/lib/
- tomcat config files such as catalina.properties, context.xml, and server.xml to be put in /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
- the application war file to be dropped in /usr/local/tomcat/webapps-javaee/
- and an entrypoint.sh file

I was hoping to find a way to basically just shove this into the tomcat base image, and proceed.

If you have any suggestions on how to go about this, or let me know if I am using the depends_on feature wrong.

Thanks!

Note: I took a look at [Share Compose configurations between files and projects](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) but couldn't find quite what I was looking for

Comment: I've used [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) before in Docker to have one Docker container read and write to a directory on the local OS.  Another container can then have read-only permissions and another bind mount to read those files.  Thus the ability to "share" data between two containers.  Not sure if it's the ideal method but...

Comment: @firefly2442 I've been playing with that, but It's not the most elegant solution, at least not the way I've ended up doing it. I'm really hoping to find an alternative, but we if not, this will not be pretty lol.